# Write only into a subset of database table columns

Tags: r, oracle, r-dbi

On Oracle I have a table with SDO_GEOMETRY data type:

```
CREATE TABLE T_GEO_TABLE
   (
    "LONGITUDE" DOUBLE, 
    "LATITUDE" DOUBLE, 
    "GEO" "SDO_GEOMETRY"
   );
```

In R i have a data frame with longitude and latitude. I want to write this table to Oracle with DBI (RJDBC) and populate the "GEO" field later with an UPDATE statement in SQL.

The function `dbWriteTable` requires the R table to have exactly the same columns as the database table. If I make an empty column "GEO" in R and try to write this table to Oracle:

```
r_table <- r_table %>% mutate(GEO = NA)
```

```
dbWriteTable(conn = con_oracle, name = "T_GEO_TABLE", value = r_table, overwrite = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

, I get an error: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY got CHAR`. The same thing happens of course with other NA types (NA_character_, NA_integer, ...).

The obvious solution is to insert first into a temporary table on Oracle with only longitude and latitude columns and then do the rest in SQL with `dbSendUpdate`.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this without the temp table? My question is not specific to SDO_GEOMETRY type. Can you somehow force a DBI function to insert into only a subset of columns.

Comment: Just found a possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72212230/inserting-r-code-outputdataframe-in-multiple-columns-of-sql-table-at-once

Comment: I don't have access to Oracle, but ... writing a subset of columns works in every other DBMS I've tried: duckdb, sqlite, postgres, sql server, and (I think) mariadb/mysql. That is, if I start with `create table r2temp (a int, b int, c int)`, I can then do `DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "r2temp", data.frame(a=1L), create=F, overwrite=F, append=T)` and it works. Does `RJDBC` specifically impose this restriction? It isn't `DBI`, and this seems like an onerous (and unnecessary) constraint that should be handled at the table level (e.g., `b INT NOT NULL`).

Comment: Can you create a view over the table and expose only the columns you will be inserting into? Then insert into the view.

Comment: @r2evans: I tried to reproduce your example. With `DBI::dbWriteTable(con_oracle, "tt_temp", data.frame(a=1L), create=F, overwrite=F, append=T)`, I get `Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object)`. With `DBI::dbWriteTable(con_oracle, "TT_TEMP", data.frame(a=1L), create=F, overwrite=F, append=T)` I get `Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (ORA-00947: not enough values)`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Interesting. `name is already used` suggests that the RJDBC driver is ignoring or misinterpreting the `create=`, `overwrite=`, and/or `append=` arguments. Sorry, since I don't use RJDBC, I can only comment on how DBI and ODBC are supposed to work given its specification and such. It works in other DBMSes, certainly suggesting either a key difference in Oracle (certainly possible), in JDBC (on which RJDBC relies), or lacking both of those possibly a mis-implementation in RJDBC (I'm assuming it's one of the first two, but who knows).

Comment: After inspecting the code with `showMethods("dbWriteTable", includeDefs = TRUE)` this could indeed be the case. Probably `dbWriteTable` can't find the lowercase table name because Oracle converts them to uppercase. It then tries to create a new one, Oracle converts it again to uppercase and throws the `name is already used` error. (I'm using an old version of RJDBC and DBI packages and am not allowd to update them since this is running on a production server...)

Answer (score 0):

Solution from Paul W in comments works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_GEO_TABLE AS
SELECT LONGITUDE, LATITUDE FROM T_GEO_TABLE;
```

```
dbWriteTable(conn = con_oracle, name = "V_GEO_TABLE", value = r_table, overwrite = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```